# How to use winapi classes?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, mount, disk-partitioning

am trying to create a project that create a file, formatting it, create a new partition and mount it, dismount it ... in C++ with Qtcretor
I found that winapi offer several function help me to do that `Format method of the Win32_Volume class` and `AddMountPoint method of the Win32_Volume class` but there is no code example show how to use it I try with [WMI C++ Application Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but in vain

can any one put me on the way please?

Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using WMI should be done in Powershell scripts, not C++.

If you're already lost at the beginning, then just limit the use of C++ to CreateProcess() function call with the reference to some Powershell script.

If you insist on writing everything in C++, then the MSDN docs should help you to use the [WMI's COM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are [samples of C++ code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). What you call "winapi classes" are really the COM interfaces with all the complications. I think you won't get away by just copy'n'pasting some lines, since COM is not as intuitive as VBScript.